# Unknown user permission :DistributeFromPersWksp while deploying profiles

Tags: ant, migration-tool

I am getting the above mentioned error in delpoying the profile .

But when i remove this from the reference of the user permission from the retrieved profile  , i dont get any error.

this is what i remove from the profile

```
<userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>DistributeFromPersWksp</name>
    </userPermissions>
```

My question are 1.)why am i getting the erroe
2.)If i remove this reference , and then do the deploy , what am i losing/drawbacks/anythin?
3.) after deploying the profile without this reference , can i add this permossion manually after its deployes successfully in the target org

thanks in advance
Samir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just removed the mapping from the package file.After researching a lot , i found that it is deprecated and does not serve much purpose

Answer (score 2):

hi Samir I am getting same error when i migrate profile from one sandbox to another. what/where is metadata DistributeFromPersWksp used and how to make it in another sandbox. both my sandboxes are on same Summer 16 release. the workaround is that you extract profile in ANT and then manually remove it from the profile and it is a pain to do in 50+ profile. were you able to resolve it

Comment: I just removed the mapping from the package file.After researching a lot , i found that it is deprecated and does not serve much purpose